# angularjs ng-repeat with date range

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm trying to filter a list that contains only the entries in a range of dates with die ui-bootstrap datepicker:

**When I load the page first time the filter works fine but when I change the dates in the datepickers no entry will be shown. How can I pass the data through the filter with the new date ranges?**

My custom filter:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
.filter('dateFilter', function () {
return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {

    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var item = items[i];

        if (item.dt > fromDate && item.dt < toDate){
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    }

    return filtered;
};
});
```

my Model:

```
var ReklaSchema = new Schema({
 dt: Date,
 order: Number,
});
```

my View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="fromDate" is-open="datepickers.fromDate" min-date="" max-date="maxDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'fromDate')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    &nbsp;bis&nbsp;
    <div class="form-group">
      <span class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="toDate" is-open="datepickers.toDate" min-date="" max-date="maxDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'toDate')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

my View for the Filter:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="rekla in reklas | dateFilter:fromDate:toDate">
      <td>{{rekla.dt | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.order}}</td>
    </tr>
```

my Controller:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Reklas, Modal) {

    $scope.newRekla = {};
    $scope.reklas = {};

    $scope.fromDate = '2015-03-31T22:00:00.000Z';
    $scope.toDate = '2015-04-30T22:00:00.000Z';

    Reklas.getAll()
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.reklas = data;
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem is the data type of the datepicker!?

Datepicker Data:

[image]

Model Data:

[image]

Comment: where you ha applied the filter ,post that html code also. And if possible provide fiddle or pluker

Comment: *add the HTML for the filter

Comment: I think the filter works but I have problem with the datepicker data which will be convert to a string when i change this one!

Answer (score 1):

Call `ng-change` function in datepicker and apply filter again in ng-change function or else put watch on date variables and in watch function apply filter again.

Answer (score 0):

you can call filter on ng-change and apply the filter on th model like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="toDate" is-open="datepickers.toDate" min-date="" max-date="maxDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" ng-change="filterDate()" close-text="Close" />
```

and in controller js create method `filterDate()` like this:

```
$scope.filterDate=function(){
    $scope.toDate=$filter('dateFilter')($scope.toDate);
}
```

Comment: I think the filter is working and the problem is the data type from the "datepicker"...I add an image in my post to see what I mean.